# MySQL join query with JSON field types

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables. In categories I have 18 records and in areas I have 8 records.

In the client_profiles table the areas field may look like [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lue8R.png)] or [2] or [1,3] etc

categories will be something along the lines of [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lue8R.png)] or [2] or [1,3] etc

A client_profile must have at least one area and at least one category.

Say I have 100 client_profiles for example. Each one belongs to an area and each one has at least one category.

lets say I am doing area = 1, I am looking for all categories (regardless) and how many client_profiles are in each category.

How do I achieve he following:

[image: results example]

etc.

table examples below.

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
category_description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
isActive boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true
);

CREATE TABLE areas (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
area_description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
isActive boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true
);

CREATE TABLE client_profiles (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
businessName VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
first_name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
last_name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
mob_no VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
areas JSON NOT NULL,
catarea JSON NOT NULL,
);

select id, areas 
from client_profiles
where JSON_CONTAINS(areas, '1',"$");

INSERT INTO categories (category_description, isActive) values 
('Accomodation', true),
('Automative', true),
('Adult', true),
('Arts & Crafts', true),
('Events', true),
('Financial', true),
('Garden', true),
('House & Home', true),
('IT & Technology', true),
('Kids', true),
('Legal', true),
('Medical', true),
('Pets', true),
('Pregnancy(Babies)', true),
('Property', true),
('Travel & Tourism', true),
('Transport', true),
('Wellness & Beauty', true);
```

Comment: May just be a typo by `‘` is a non ascii quote

Comment: Is your JSON data `'[1, 2, 3, 4]'` or `'["1", "2", "3", "4"]'`?

Comment: Can you show some sample data that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Go on, give the 18 records too.

Comment: it is '[1, 2, 3, 4]'

Comment: And you're storing a list of categories in a column called `catarea`?  Or is that a typo?

Comment: @MatBailie - its an array in a json field

Comment: @wayne - Yes, and I'm asking if that json *column* is called `catarea` because that's a strange name for a list of categories........

Comment: @MatBailie - yes, catarea is the list of categories, and yes, I agree its a strange name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this...

```
SELECT
  c.id,
  COUNT(p.id)
FROM
  categories        c
LEFT JOIN
  client_profiles   p
    ON  JSON_CONTAINS(p.areas,      '1',                    '$')
    AND JSON_CONTAINS(p.categories, CAST(c.id AS CHAR(32)), '$')
GROUP BY
  c.id
```